# Mechanical energy of a body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

What is the total mechanical energy of an air-plane flying in the sky? Does it possess both kinetic energy and potential energy,taking the zero potential energy at ground? As it is moving it will possess kinetic energy and, as it is flying at a height from the ground it will possess potential energy; is this true?

Comment: yes this is true.

Comment: is this the same condition for the total mechanical energy of a flying bullet?@AdiRo